# how to compare elements of two list in python

Tags: python

a1.txt file has data which shows the student id and assignment marks:

2345|8

9798|7

student.txt file has data which shows the student id, first name, last name:

2345|joy|smith

9798|peter|Jones

so, from the two file, I need an output of those students who have submitted assignments.

the output would be:

```
2345 roy,smith,8
9798 peter,jones,7
```

how can i get above output in python?

Comment: Not sure how you're getting that output. Please explain the process

Comment: a1.txt file has data which shows the student id and assignment marks:
2345|8
9798|7

student.txt file has data which shows the student id, first name, last name:
2345|joy|smith
9798|peter|Jones

so, from the two file, I made two list list1 and list2.
now I need an output of those students who have submitted assignments.

Comment: Please edit the original question itself to provide more details

Comment: @MananPrajapati I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with open('a1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('student.txt', 'r') as file2:
    list_1 = file1.readlines()
    list_2 = file2.readlines()
    for i in list_1:
        i = i.split('|')
        for j in list_2:
            j = j.split('|')
            if i[0] == j[0]:
                print(i[0], j[1], j[2].replace('\n', ''), i[1].replace('\n', ''), sep=",")
```

Comment: I tried this one, but it only prints the last record, not all. It prints  9798,peter, jones,7.  It doesn't show another matched data.

Comment: @MananPrajapati You are right, there was a little bug there. I fixed it, check now!

Answer (score 0):

Convert one of the lists to dict for efficient lookup:

```
>>> dict1 = {k: v for (k, *v) in list1}
>>> result = [[k, *v, *dict1[k]] for (k, *v) in list2 if k in dict1]
>>> result
[['2345', 'roy', 'smith', '8'], ['9798', 'peter', 'jones', '7']]
```